# UK visitor visa after a visa refusal

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, standard-visitor-visas, moroccan-citizens

I am about to re-apply for a UK visitor visa after being refused.

Now we are planning on a worldwide trip starting in November and, at the start, my wife wants us to spend a week UK to see her family.

What type of visa I should apply for now? Is there a chance of refusal? What could I do to improve my chances? Should I include a letter explaining the reason for the trip?

Comment: It’s obvious your chances of success are very slim given all you have written. The circumstances are no different from when you were refused, probably worse.

Comment: The chances hugely depend on the reason for refusal of the previous visa. Can you tell us, or attach an edited copy of the refusal?

Answer (score 4):

Your only option is a Standard Visitor Visa https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y There is of course a chance of refusal since, given your plans to go on a world trip, you may find it difficult to demonstrate sufficient ties to Morocco and intention to leave. Including your planned itinerary and evidence of booked travel for your world trip may help, as would including details of any assets (joint or otherwise) you have in Morocco e.g. savings, property; conversely, being married to a UK citizen and being unable to show strong ties to home may harm your chance of success.

Comment: @caliaoss It may well help, especially if you can provide leave of absence confirmation from your employer plus trading accounts for your company and clarification of who will run it on your behalf while you’re away on your world tour.